# ClickOne updating application on local machine

Tags: c#, clickonce

I am working on **VS 2010 with .net 4 (OS: Windows XP)**. I want my application to have update feature. I have only one computer. How can i deploy the application it to test the update feature?

Currently i am publishing my application in a folder in `my documents`
I tried publishing to local FTP using XAMPP but it was unable to check for updates on FTP.
Now i have installed IIS to make a local HTTP server to deploy my application there but it asks for `Front Page Server Extension` then was asking `Front Page`.

All i need is that my application can update it self. Original requirement was `patch update` but i don't know how to do that. I think using `ClickOnce` is enough.

Comment: can u tell me the OS you are using to host clickonce package?

Comment: What version of XP? You should be able to install IIS and publish to localhost. This article might help: http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/local-deployment-of-a-clickonce-application/ Are you running an Express version of VS? If so, install VS WebDeveloper Express and it will take care of the FPSE requirement.

Comment: Windows XP SP2 Pro. No, i am using VS 2010 ultimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a network share on your local machine and publish to that; when you install the application, make sure to install it via the network share too.

Comment: can you please add some more detail? After creating network share, where will i deploy the application with what options? They are confusing. e.g. different installation and publish folder

Comment: In most cases, the installation URL and publish file location are the same. Just use \\myshare\myfolder\ for both.